# Is it possible to force eslint to ignore `eslint-disable` directives?

Tags: javascript, eslint

I have a 3rd party generated library in my codebase, and I'd like to lint it with a specific set of rules. Unfortunately, the generated library includes `/* eslint-disable */` in the file. I'd like to avoid using `sed` to remove that line if possible, so if there's a way to explicitly tell `eslint` to lint a disabled file, that's the way I'd like to go.

Comment: Why do you even need to lint a 3rd party generated library? What is the point? it's just a dependency you should be consuming.

Comment: I was about to ask that: dependencies should not need linting, linting is for finding errors in _your_ code, not in other people's code that aren't part of your project, so your eslint target should be your own source dirs, never your node_modules or vendor etc. dirs (and never `./**/*.js` =)

Comment: What do you mean by "*generated library*"? And notice you should lint *source* files, not generated files.

Comment: I am using a custom lint rule to ensure that certain required properties are set in the generated code. Ideally, I would be able to set those rules in the product that generates the library but that's not a feature they offer at the moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use the [--no-inline-config](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/command-line-interface#--no-inline-config) command line option.